# Dropbox .NET SDK failed to install (One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, dropbox-api

I would like to use the DropBox SDK (https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet
) in my c# project.

When I add using NuGet, I get the following error:

Package Dropbox.Api 4.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Dropbox.Api 4.3.0 supports:
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-dnxcore50+net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50)
  - portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile328)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.

Lots of searching (including on Stack Overflow) points to needing to add an entry in my .csproj file.  Indeed, the SDK says you need to add a reference.  I've amended my file as follows but I still get the error.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='Net45'">portable-net45win8+wp8+wpa81+dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: To me, the error message seems pretty clear. The SDK seems to be incompatible with .Net core. Is it possible for you to use standard .Net framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portable version of the Dropbox package is supported on .NET Core, your csproj file however contains a `Condition` that does not enable the package target fallback. you can change your csproj to this for the snipped you posted:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);dnxcore50</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The value for `PackageTargetFallback` can also be `portable-net45+win8` like explain on their [README file on GitHub](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/README.md). For the upcoming .NET Core 2.0, this fallback should no longer be needed.